# How can energy conservation not be violated in stimulated emission processes?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, quantum-optics, spectroscopy, photon-emission

Fermis golden rule, derived from time-dependent perturbation theory, give the rate for a quantum system, disturbed by a weak harmonic pertubation with frequency $\omega$, to transition from a state $|i\rangle$ with energy $E_i$ in a continuum of states with energy $E_f+dE=E_i\pm \hbar \omega +dE$
$$
W_{i\rightarrow f}=\frac{2\pi}{\hbar}|\langle i | V | f\rangle |^2\rho(E_f) \tag{4.12}
$$

Considered now the process of stimulated emission. In [1] it is said concerning the density of states $\rho$

> In the standard case of transitions between quantized levels in an
> atom, the initial and final electron states are discrete. In this
> case, the density of final states factor that enters eqn 4.12 is the
> density of photon states.

I get from this that one should consider $|\textrm{state}\rangle$ not just as the state of the electron, but also from the photon.

We know that the emission of photons and therefore their density of states is distributed according to the linewidth function in atomic emission.

What I don't get now is how it can be that some excitations release more energy than others, despite the electrons always experiencing the same energy change. Where does the excess energy for the more energy rich photons on the upper end of the line width come from?

[1] Fox, Mark (2006). Quantum Optics: An Introduction. Oxford: Oxford University Press. p. 51. ISBN 9780198566731.

Comment: Hey, did you find the answer?

Comment: @Razor not really..